# No energy loss in IndustrialCraft2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft

I have Minecraft 1.8.9 with BuildCraft and IndustrialCraft 2-2.3.263-ex18.

I have two butboxes, one with 40000EU, and second with 0EU. I connected this butboxes with copper cuble length of 50 blocks:

[image: tow butboxes, connected with copper cuble length of 50 blocks]

As of [IC2 wiki](https://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Copper_Cable) copper cuble should lost 1EU per 5 blocks, so I expect that `40000/32*22` = 27500EU will come from one batbox to another one, and 
`40000/32*10` = 12500EU will lost. But no energy was lost and all 40000EU moved from one batbox to another. What is wrong with my calculations?

Comment: So... Your question is why you get more than you expected? :D Have you tried other energy storages on one/both ends?

Comment: Yes, it is my question :) I tried with CESU and get the same effect. I read somewhere that sometimes there is a bug in ic2: all coubles have infinity capable and no lost. So i thing maybe my ic2 installation have this bug.

Comment: Ok, then that's probably the answer. Do you still want to keep this question open in case someone is sure about it?

Comment: Yes, maybe someone knows something about this